# I want user start long complex backround task and control it's execution in Android. What to use?

Tags: android, background-process

I want user to start some complex background task and observe it's progres and being able to stop it. The process should not stop on screen rotation or application sent to background. The process should stop if user closes an application. The process should stop if user presses appropriate button.

What to use?

1. Just create a Thread? How would my Activity remember a thread after screen rotate or backgrounded? I can't serialize/parcelalize thread.
2. Background service? It is said deprecated here: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service
3. Immediate/Exact/Deferred from here https://developer.android.com/guide/background
   But what namely? Diagram infers I should use `Deffered`, but the name contradicts, because I don't want to defer an execution.

Pls clarify.

Answer (score 1):

We have MvvM architecture to tackle your problem, the ViewModel(A simple java/kt class) will still have its instance when the activity or fragment changes its configurations like(Device rotated, keyboard attached/detached etc). You can run your long task in viewmodel, and listen to the changes in your activity.

Like: ->
MyViewModel.kt

```
val longWork = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun performLongWork(){
    // This is a viewmodel scope, which means, 
    // if the user has left the UI screen, any work that was started within
    // this scope will finish and not report any result. But if you want to 
    // still continue the work even if the user left the screen, 
    // use CoroutineScope(IO).launch{}
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //Some looooong task
        delay(50000)
        longWork.postValue("Completed :)")
    }
}
```

Then in your activity or fragment

```
private fun observeWork() {
    myViewModel.longWork.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let { result ->
            // Update the user that the work has completed
            myTextView.setText(result)
        }
    })
}
```

If you want the work to be completed no matter what, even if the app is closed, or the device is restarted go for the below approach.
Just quoting from Android docs:

WorkManager is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts.

[WorkManagerLink](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) - This will also run immediately if you say it to.

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context)
.beginWith(workA)
.enqueue()
```

But if you add constraints like run when the device is charging, then this will obviously defer your execution.

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
.setRequiresCharging(true)
.build()

val myWorkRequest: WorkRequest =
OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
   .setConstraints(constraints)
   .build()
```

A very good video - [Youtube Android Developers - Work Manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz0z694SrEE)